# Closing application in FormClosing event

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to close my application when closing the menu form. 
This is my code:

```
private void frmMenu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application",
        "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //this.Close();
        Application.Exit();
        //e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

When closing this message appears twice.

Comment: Calling Application.Exit() triggers the FormClosing event on forms that are not closed yet.  Including this one.  Use a bool field in your class.  Or just don't spam the user with a needless message box.

Comment: +1 to Hans Passant's last point. How often do users accidentally hit a window's `[X]` button, and how often do they do they actually mean it? The popup is only helpful in the former case, yet the latter case is probably much more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `OnFormClosing` method:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if (!e.Cancel) {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes) {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or following [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s advice in the comments on using a bool (e.g. `IsDataValid`) in your class:

```
private void frmMenu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{ 
   if (!IsDataValid)
   {
       if(DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(Do you want to close this application?",
        "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
           this.Dispose(); //or Application.Exit();
       else
            e.Cancel = true;
   }
   else
       this.Dispose(); //or Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do the exit again, just let it pass:

```
private void frmMenu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?",
        "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get two messages because `Application.Exit();` is closing `frmMenu`, whereas you are currently closing it => `frmMenu` is closed twice.

If `frmMenu` is the main form of your application, meaning you should having something like that in your *Program.cs* file:

```
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FrmMenu());
    }
}
```

... then the application will exit when closing `frmMenu`. As said by *derape*, you then don't have to call `Application.Exit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void frmMenu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
```